# Run exec() without connection to the main program in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, exec

I am trying to create a python 3 IDE and text editor in python to learn more about `tkinter`. In it (because it *is* an IDE) I am attempting to run code entered by the user. The best way that I could find was to use `exec()`. This works, as show in the IDLE below:

```
>>> exec(input('PROMPT: '))
PROMPT: print('Hello World') #Entered in by user, this could be anything.
Hello World # <-- Output
```

Yet, the `exec()` function knows about its surroundings.

```
>>> important_variable = 'important value' #Say that this is important.
>>> exec(input('PROMPT: '))
PROMPT: important_variable = 'meaningless value' #In the IDE, user unknowingly re-assigns to a meaningless value
>>> important_variable #look at the value
'meaningless value' #Yes, the value was changed.
```

This is not what I want. I want no connection to the main program, other then values I put in. (for example, changing the `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, and `sys.stderr` values to a `tkinter` GUI)

My idea was to use the extended use of the `exec()` function (brought to you be `help()`):

```
exec(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)
    Execute the given source in the context of globals and locals.

    The source may be a string representing one or more Python statements
    or a code object as returned by compile().
    The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
    defaulting to the current globals and locals.
    If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
```

I tried to use a empty dict for globals, and I left locals blank. This seems to work at a first look.

```
>>> important_variable = 'important value'
>>> exec_globals = {} #create a black dict of globals
>>> exec(input('PROMPT: '), exec_globals) #pass in the blank dict
PROMPT: important_variable = 'meaningless value' #change to value?
>>> important_variable #look at the value
'important value' #value is kept!
```

However, the program the code was run by is seen in exceptions:

```
>>> exec_globals = {} #create a black dict of globals
>>> exec(input('PROMPT: '), exec_globals) #pass in the blank dict
PROMPT: THIS SHALL CAUSE A ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#288>", line 1, in <module>
    exec(input('PROMPT: '), exec_globals) # <-- YOU CAN SEE THE CODE
  File "<string>", line 1
    THIS SHALL CAUSE A ERROR!
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I prevent this from happening and remove any connection to the program as seen from the code that is entered by the user. I would still like some control in the program however, like changing the values of `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, and `sys.stderr`. Is `exec(source, blank_dict)` the way to go, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging around, I found the answer to my question.

The answer is in the `code` module. As the [python documentation on the code module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html) states:

> The code module provides facilities to implement read-eval-print loops in Python.

Basically tools to simulate code running. The function that the code module gives doesn't only just help with a read-eval-print loop, but it can also run code without a connection to the main program. Take this program called `runcode.py` for a example:

```
import code

important_variable = 'important value'

program = '\n'.join([
            'for n in range(10):',
            '    print(n)',
            'important_variable = None',
            'def error(): raise Exception()',
            'error()',
            ])

interpreter = code.InteractiveInterpreter()
interpreter.runsource(program, '<FAKE MEANINGLESS FILE NAME>', 'exec')

print()
print(important_variable)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<FAKE MEANINGLESS FILE NAME>", line 5, in <module> #No connection!
  File "<FAKE MEANINGLESS FILE NAME>", line 4, in error #No connection!
Exception

important value
```

If you are reading from a real file, replace `'<FAKE MEANINGLESS FILE NAME>'` with the absolute path to the file. This will give you a more advanced traceback (error message will include what was on the line)

The great thing is that this works with a setup and end scripts, like so:

```
import code

program = '\n'.join([
            'for n in range(10):',
            '    print(n)',
            'def error(): raise Exception()',
            'error()',
            ])

interpreter = code.InteractiveInterpreter()

#Setup code. This could change sys.stdin, stdout, etc. and setup variables!
interpreter.runsource('setup_stuff = None', 'whatever name you want', 'exec')

#Run code
interpreter.runsource(program, '<FAKE MEANINGLESS FILE NAME>', 'exec')

#Process Code now that the program is done, this might get the values in local() or something like that.
interpreter.runsource(program, 'whatever name you want', 'exec')
```

And that's it!